# Literal '#' character in C preprocessor macro replacement-list?

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any way in which we can have literal '#' character in replacement-list of C preprocessor macro?

'#' character in replacement-list of C preprocessor is an operator that performs stringification of argument, for example-

```
#define foo(words) #words

foo(Hello World!)
```

will result-

```
"Hello World!"
```

Is there any way we can have '#' as a literal character in replacement-list like-

```
#define foo(p1, p2) p1 # p2
                    // ^ is there any way to specify that- this isn't # operator?
foo(arg1, arg2) // will result-
arg1 "arg2"
// What I wanted was
// arg1 # arg2
```

I tried a macro like-

```
#define foo(p1, p2, p3) p1 p2 p3
// And then
foo(arg1, #, arg2)
// Which resulted in
arg1 # arg2
```

This was getting the work done but wasn't better than typing `arg1 # arg2` manually.

Then I tried defining a `foo` macro which in turn will call `metafoo` with '#' as argument-

```
#define metafoo(p1, p2, p3) p1 p2 p3
#define foo(p1, p2) metafoo(p1, #, p2)
foo(arg1, arg2)
```

which resulted in a error `error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter`, because # was getting interpreted like stringification operator.

Comment: Please tag question with specific compiler.

Comment: When would you want to expand `#` to a literal operator and not to a `"#"` string?

Comment: @DanielKleinstein I was trying to mess with `#include` directive and and define a macro `use` such that it would expand `use(stdio)` to `#include<stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily solved with:

```
#define NumberSign  #
#define foo(p1, p2) p1 NumberSign p2

foo(arg1, arg2)
```

which yields:

```
arg1 # arg2
```

The reason it works is that `#` is an operator in function-like macros (macros with parameters) but has no effect in object-like macros (macros without parameters).

Comment: Accepting this answer because it provides a good explanation, though @AllanWind's answer helped me solve the problem first. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
#define metafoo(p1, p2, p3) p1 p2 p3
#define hash #
#define foo(p1, p2) metafoo(p1, hash, p3)
foo(arg1, arg2)
```

In `foo` you probably mean `p2` instead of `p3`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Your answer works, however compiler was having issues with the `hash` definition, and producing `error: stray ‘#’ in program`, this can be solved by preprocessing and compiling in separate steps.

Comment: If this was a suitable answer I suggest holding off accepting it in case others have better ideas.

Comment: Yes. waiting just for that.